# Visual Studio C programming: Unresolved external symbol, but visible in watch window

Tags: c, visual-studio, linker, extern

In my main.c , i have :

```
int myvar[4] = {0,1,2,3};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  ...................

}
```

When I try to access myvar in another file as below:

```
extern int myvar[4];

if (myvar[0] == 1) do something;
```

When I build this (after cleaning the project), errors "LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _myvar" and "fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals" are observed. But if I comment the 'if' statement alone, then the solution builds fine and I can observe the correct values for **myvar** in the watch window in debug mode. I am confused regarding why this is happening. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: different file in the same linking unit or different linking unit (i.e. two different libs)?

Comment: two different libs @eckes

Comment: I want to know how your "build" makes it to the link-phase in the first place since (a) you cannot assign a fixed array in C, and (b) the declaration for `main()` is non-standard (second parameter is an array of pointer-to-*poiner-to* `char` ??), (c) `if {myvar[0] == 1}` isn't legal C either. Check spellings and decls, since nothing else in this seems to be real code and therefore stands no chance of reproduction.

Comment: that was just sloppy quoting of the code with a confused mix of C and Matlab ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention in your comment that the usage is split up into two different libs, you need to set up a dependency for the **using** library (the one that has `extern int myvar[4];`) to the **providing** library (the lib providing the `main` function and declaring `int myvar[4]`).

However, this could lead you into the problem that you have circurlar dependencies: usually the library providing the `main` function will call some functions in other libraries.

If you need `myvar` in your **using** library, then pass it down with an `init` function that gets called in order to initialize the **using** library.

An example for your work to be done assuming that the `main()` function is provided by `lib_a` and the library accessing `myvar` is called `lib_b`:

In `lib_a` do the following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  lib_b_init(sizeof(myvar)/sizeof(*myvar), myvar);
  /* rest of your code goes here */
}
```

In `lib_b` in addition to the functions already provided, add the following:

```
static int* g_libb_myvar        = (int*) 0; /* local pointer to myvar of lib_a */
static int  g_libb_myvar_size   = 0;        /* to note the length of the array */

/* Initializer for lib_b
 *
 * @param    a_count  number of elements held in the a_myvar array
 * @param    a_myvar  array getting passed down by caller
 * */
void lib_b_init( int a_count, int* a_myvar ) {
  g_libb_myvar_size = a_count;
  g_libb_myvar      = a_myvar; /* now, you could use g_libb_myvar in lib_b */
}
```

Comment: thanks ! can u elaborate a bit on the init part @eckes